# Need Help Trimming File Name Text

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory with 300 files that have the naming convention as follows:

```
file.pdf_error
```

And I need to remove the _error part of the file.

I tried

```
rename 's/pdf_error/pdf/' *pdf_error
```

but this command doesn't do anything.

Assistance please?

Comment: If you have the `rename` command, I think that should work.

Comment: It doesnt work - I need an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `rename` is not perl rename utility. Use this `mv` script:

```
for f in *.pdf_error; do
   mv "$f" "${f%_error}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much - life saver!

Comment: Can you tell me what the "${f%_error}" is actually doing?

Comment: `${f%_error}` is removing text `_error` from the end of variable `$f`. Check `man bash` for more details on BASH string manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `rename` with the right syntax:

```
rename pdf_error pdf *pdf_error
```